# Cannot suppress browser logs in Geckodriver

Tags: selenium-firefoxdriver, geckodriver

I am running Geckodriver (and Firefox) and apparently Gecko is flooded with an error from FF (see below). I am not using any addons and I don't know why is it there. I wanted to suppress it so that the logs do not contain anything from the browser. I set log level to fatal but it seems that it only affects geckodriver's own logs, but not those from the browser.

I start geckodriver with this command:

```
./geckodriver.exe --port=4567 --binary="C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" --log fatal
```

Then I create session by manually sending HTTP request POST request to \session:

```
{
  "desiredCapabilities": {
    "acceptInsecureCerts": true,
    "loggingPrefs": {
      "server": "OFF",
      "performance": "OFF",
      "driver": "OFF",
      "browser": "OFF",
      "client": "OFF"
    },
    "browserName": "firefox",
    "moz:firefoxOptions": {
      "args": []
    },
    "version": "",
    "platform": "ANY"},
  "requiredCapabilities": {},
  "capabilities": {
    "desiredCapabilities": {
      "acceptInsecureCerts": true,
      "loggingPrefs": {
        "server": "OFF",
        "performance": "OFF",
        "driver": "OFF",
        "browser": "OFF",
        "client": "OFF"
      },
      "browserName": "firefox",
      "version": "",
      "platform": "ANY"
    },
    "requiredCapabilities": {},
    "alwaysMatch": {
      "acceptInsecureCerts": true
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the output I'm getting within the first few seconds:

```
1496327277282   addons.manager  ERROR   startup failed: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsIFile.create]"  nsresult: "0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm :: FileUtils_getDir :: line 70"  data: no] Stack trace: FileUtils_getDir()@resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm:70 < FileUtils_getFile()@resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm:42 < validateBlocklist()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:671 < startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:834 < startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:3129 < observe()@resource://gre/components/addonManager.js:65
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm, line 1657: NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED: AddonManager is not initialized
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
...
```

This line is repeated hundreds of times per second

How to suppress this log or fix the root cause?

EDIT:
After some research I found out that this line is printed to the standard output when I run firefox.exe from command line (without gecko)

Answer (score 0):

I use Eclipse IDE for Java Developers Version: 2019-12 (4.14.0),
Firefox75.0 (64 bit),
testng 7.1.0,
selenium-java 3.141.59
eclipse Console display
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'safemon64.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/ 
I don't know how to handle it.